# how to run a script in the PyCharm terminal using code

Tags: python, pycharm

I want to run a script

```bash
pythonw ./main.py
```

in my Pycharm terminal using code.  I tried to run it in the command prompt using

```py
p = subprocess.Popen(["start", "cmd", "/k", "command"], shell = True)
```

but the script does not work.  I want to run it in the terminal from code.

Comment: `"command"` should be `"pythonw ./main.py"`.

Comment: While this is possible, it would likely be a cleaner approach to simply `import` the other module you want to run -- or, even better, put the code you'll be using in one or more functions, import the module, and call its function(s).

Answer (score 0):

What you did WILL run a command, but that command will be in a different shell, detatched from the current running shell unless you do work to connect the output of the spawned shell to the shell running in PyCharm.

A betterway is to use [runpy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/runpy.html) - The runpy module is part of the core library since Python 3.2.

Minimal working example:

**1.py**

```py
from runpy import run_path
from pathlib import Path

print("1: start")
my_script = Path("2.py")
y = 10

d = {"y": y}
print(f"Input: y={y}")

assert my_script.exists(), f"Problem: I could not find {my_script}"
res = run_path(my_script, d)
y=res['y']

print(f"Result: y={y}")

print("1: done")
```

**2.py**

```py
print("2: start")

if "y" not in globals():
    y = "y not Set, please run 1.py"

print(f"y={y} - making y bigger")

y *= 15

print("2: done")
```

If you need to use multiple processors (i.e. multiple concurrent Python interpreters) then you should take a look at [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html)*, which can also make use of runpy and provides simple consistent and flexible access to all of runpy, threading and multiprocessing.

As shown in the exmaple, above, runpy provides the advantage that you can directly alter and access the sub-program input and output as true Python objects from and to the parent program without resorting text processing STDIO printed or screen scraped data.

* See a working toy example of concurrent.futures working with runpy in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/the-moog/415965a83074366d386db2baf5b6a371)